# Can I undo a `sudo chown -R /` on Mojave?

Tags: unix, permissions, operating-systems, sudo, chown

I ran a command that ended up executing as

```
sudo chown -R /
```

Can I revert `/` to default permissions?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not, sorry. But you could e.g. boot a CD/USB Live System to check what the correct permissions should look like.